# SwiftUI: Selecting inner NavigationList item from Toolbar

Tags: swiftui, toolbar, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to have an inner list item highlighted from a toolbar button. This is actually to highlight a new entry after clicking on the New button.

```
import SwiftUI

var listItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
var secondItems = ["Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3"]

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var select: String? = "Item 1"
    @State var second: String? = "Second 1"

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List
            {
                ForEach((0..<listItems.count), id: \.self)
                {index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ListView(secondSelection: self.second), tag: listItems[index], selection: $select)
                    {
                        Text(listItems[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar
        {
            Button(action: {addNewItem()})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
            Button(action: {selectItem(index: 1)})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
            Button(action: {selectItem(index: 2)})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "2.circle")
            }
            Button(action: {selectItem(index: 3)})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "3.circle")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addNewItem()
    {
        let c = secondItems.count + 1
        secondItems.append("Second \(c)")
    }
    
    func selectItem(index: Int)
    {
        print ("\(index) selected")
        self.second = "Second \(index)"
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    @State var secondSelection: String? = "Item 1"
    @State var select: String? = nil

    init(secondSelection: String?)
    {
        self.secondSelection = secondSelection
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List()
            {
                ForEach(secondItems, id: \.self)
                {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item, selection: $select)
                    {
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
     }
}

struct DetailView: View
{
    @State var item: String

    var body: some View
    {
        Text(item)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Clicking on the "1", "2" and "3" button in the toolbar should highlight the item "Second 1", "Second 2", and "Second 3". I can get the outer list to highlight, but not the inner list. At the moment it's not doing anything.

And what I am ultimately trying to do is click the addNewItem and see the new item appear in the second list, highlighted and ready to go.

**UPDATE**

I have made some progress with this.

```
import SwiftUI

class SelectedItem: ObservableObject
{
    static let shared = SelectedItem() //singleton
    
    @Published var item: String? = "Item 1"
    @Published var second: String? = "Second 2"
}

var listItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
var secondItems = ["Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3"]

struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var selectedItem = SelectedItem.shared

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List
            {
                ForEach((0..<listItems.count), id: \.self)
                {index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ListView(), tag: listItems[index], selection: $selectedItem.item)
                    {
                        Text(listItems[index])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar
        {
            Button(action: {addNewItem()})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }
            Button(action: {selectItem(index: 1)})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
            Button(action: {selectItem(index: 2)})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "2.circle")
            }
            Button(action: {selectItem(index: 3)})
            {
                Label("Select", systemImage: "3.circle")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addNewItem()
    {
        let index = secondItems.count + 1
        secondItems.append("Second \(index)")
        selectItem(index: index)
        
    }
    
    func selectItem(index: Int)
    {
        print ("\(index) selected")
        let second = "Second \(index)"
        selectedItem.second = second
    }
}

struct ListView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var selectedItem = SelectedItem.shared

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List()
            {
                ForEach(secondItems, id: \.self)
                {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item, selection: $selectedItem.second)
                    {
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View
{
    @State var item: String

    var body: some View
    {
        Text(item)
    }
}
```

Now when I click on one of the numeric buttons it will highlight the inner text. Annoyingly it will not select the inner item if I have just appended a new item to the list.

Actually this does sort of work some of the time. It seems that if you repeatedly click it it works every other time, until it goes off screen where it will start working every time. I suspect it is a timing thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass binding to internal list instead of value, like

```
NavigationLink(destination: ListView(secondSelection: $second),    // << here !!
   tag: listItems[index], selection: $select)
```

and use it as selection in

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    @Binding var secondSelection: String?   // << here !!
    @State var select: String? = nil

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            List(selection: $secondSelection)     // << and here !!
            {
                ForEach(secondItems, id: \.self)
                {item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item), tag: item, selection: $select)
                    {
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

**Note:** *as known binding is not reliable between different view hierarchies, so I would recommend to refactor this selection into ObservableObject-based view model, which can be passed by reference anywhere.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that didn't change anything. Nothing is highlighted when you click the 1, 2 and 3 buttons.